# How to split the prefetched image dataset(downloaded from datasetbuilder)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

Can you please let me know that is it possible to split the dataset downloaded from the tensorflow datasetbuilder into training, testing and validation, specially when the split section shows only train on the tensorflow website

Answer (score 0):

```
n = len(dataset)
train_size = int(n*0.7)
test_size = n - train_size
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)
train_data = dataset.take(train_size)
test_size = dataset.skip(test_size)
```